# Change face using dir locals file

Tags: faces, directory-local-variables, face-attributes

I am trying to set face for org blocks to invisible for certain folders, so that it is nicer to read the org files with code. I am using `.dir-locals.el` file.

So, this example for the begin line works:

`((org-mode . ((eval . (face-remap-add-relative 'org-block-begin-line '(:foreground "#282c34"))))))`

But the following doesn't seem to work. Although, when I evaluate the `face-attribute` part it gives the above colour string.

`((org-mode . ((eval . (face-remap-add-relative 'org-block-begin-line '(:foreground (face-attribute 'default :background)))))))`

I've tried quoting the `face-attribute` function, didn't help.

Comment: You probably need to use `backquote`: `` ;;`(:background ,(face-attribute 'default :background) ``. See [Backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) (aargh - I can't remember how to quote the backquote...)

Comment: Yep. That worked. I have seen the commas around, never really new what they do. :). Thanks!

Comment: There are 58 other questions linked to the one I linked to above, that is canonically used to mark duplicates for this problem. Even though they are all duplicates (in the sense that for all of them the answer is `backquote`), they all appear at first glance to be different - and yet they are not. This one is another manifestation of the same problem.

Comment: Yes, both the doc link and the post link answered my question. Thanks.